# gcc/g++ library issues when moving development from Solaris 8 to Solaris 10 (gcc 3.2.1)

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, solaris-10

first of all a little background about myself: I am not a C/C++ developer, though I learned quite a lot about C and system programming years ago. My primary occupation is Unix admin (with a slant towards Solaris) and I'm trying to help some in-house developers to migrate their development environments from Solaris 8 to Solaris 10.

They used to develop their applications on Solaris 8 up until now. But recently the last Solaris 8 Development machine has been turned off but of course no one bothered to really test if all the applications would compile as well in Solaris 10 as they did in Solaris 8.

Now we have a very specific application that must be compiled with gcc 3.2.1 - I have managed to get the developers to be able to compile, however, the compiled binary won't run in the Production environment - it does in the development environment, though.

The reason for the failure of the compiled binary in the production system is that some libraries are missing:

```
./myapp 
ld.so.1: myapp: fatal: libstdc++.so.5: open failed: No such file or directory
Killed
```

Now the strange thing is, that this library (and libgcc_s.so.1, too) were not linked against, when the binary was built in Solaris 8 - here are the two outputs of ldd for comparison, first the new one built on Solaris 10 (note the two lines reading "file not found"):

```
ldd myapp
    librt.so.1 =>    /lib/64/librt.so.1
    libpthread.so.1 =>       /lib/64/libpthread.so.1
    libstdc++.so.5 =>        (file not found)
    libm.so.2 =>     /lib/64/libm.so.2
    libgcc_s.so.1 =>         (file not found)
    libc.so.1 =>     /lib/64/libc.so.1
    libaio.so.1 =>   /lib/64/libaio.so.1
    libmd.so.1 =>    /lib/64/libmd.so.1
    /platform/SUNW,Netra-T12/lib/sparcv9/libc_psr.so.1
    /platform/SUNW,Netra-T12/lib/sparcv9/libmd_psr.so.1
```

And now the older binary which was still compiled in a "true" Solaris 8 environment:

```
ldd myapp
    libm.so.1 =>     /lib/64/libm.so.1
    librt.so.1 =>    /lib/64/librt.so.1
    libpthread.so.1 =>       /lib/64/libpthread.so.1
    libc.so.1 =>     /lib/64/libc.so.1
    libaio.so.1 =>   /lib/64/libaio.so.1
    libmd.so.1 =>    /lib/64/libmd.so.1
    libm.so.2 =>     /lib/64/libm.so.2
    /platform/SUNW,Netra-T12/lib/sparcv9/libc_psr.so.1
    /platform/SUNW,Netra-T12/lib/sparcv9/libmd_psr.so.1
```

The only difference I know of (except for the completely different OS environment) is that the gcc call they used to use in Solaris 8 didn't work in Solaris 10. When trying to compile a very simple C++ program we ran into a lot of errors (the example code is widely used in multiple variations across the net):

```
$ cat easy.cpp 
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
        std::cout << "Welcome to the wonderful world of C++!!!\n";
        return 0;
}
```

The result of using "gcc" as the command (gcc32 is actually a link to gcc in our environment, as g++32 links to g++ (with the appropriate version 3.2.1)):

```
$ gcc32 -m64 -o easy easy.cpp
/var/tmp//ccWzG0Lj.o: In function `main':
/var/tmp//ccWzG0Lj.o(.text+0x4): undefined reference to `std::cout'
/var/tmp//ccWzG0Lj.o(.text+0x8): undefined reference to `std::cout'
/var/tmp//ccWzG0Lj.o(.text+0xc): undefined reference to `std::cout'
/var/tmp//ccWzG0Lj.o(.text+0x18): undefined reference to `std::cout'
/var/tmp//ccWzG0Lj.o(.text+0x34): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)'
/var/tmp//ccWzG0Lj.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
/var/tmp//ccWzG0Lj.o(.text+0xa4): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::Init[in-charge]()'
/var/tmp//ccWzG0Lj.o(.text+0xec): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::~Init [in-charge]()'
/var/tmp//ccWzG0Lj.o(.eh_frame+0x12): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

When I called g++ directly, the program compiled with only one warning:

```
$ g++32 -m64 -o easy easy.cpp
/home/user/tools/bin/ld: warning: libm.so.1, needed by /home/user/tools/gcc32/lib/gcc-lib/sparc-sun-solaris2.8/3.2.1/../../../sparcv9/libstdc++.so, may conflict with libm.so.2
```

When I tried to run it I first also encountered the missing libstdc++.so.5 library but being on the development machine a tweak of LD_LIBRARY_PATH solved this problem.

However: the target production machines don't have libstdc++.so.5 installed (they have version 6) and although it *might* be possible to install an extra gcclib package the question remains: why does the call with g++ link to those two extra libraries while the call with gcc doesn't - or, rephrased: how can I compile the binary so it doesn't need the extra libraries, as it didn't need them before, when it was compiled in Solaris 8?

Thanks very much in advance for your patience (it has become quite a long text) and any hint is most appreciated.

Kind regards,

Henning

Comment: Using g++ to link will automatically link all thats needed for the standard library to work fine. Compile and link everything with the new gcc, and nothing will need the version 5 (version 6 was introduced with gcc 3 something). You can not mix stuff compiled with both versions of gcc.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have the option to use a different gcc. The app *must* be compiled with gcc 3.2.1 (for reasons unbeknownst to me). The same gcc package, that is now installed in our new Solaris 10 development machine was previously installed in the old Solaris 8 machine, too. So I'd expect that, unless I've been missing something, I can compile the app in the same way in Solaris 10 as they previously could compile it in Solaris 8 - as I said, I am more of an admin so it is very possible, that something eludes me here...

Comment: binaries/object files of the two gccs that your objects are compiled with are incompatible. dont mix them. use a single gcc version to compile everything.

Comment: You may try -static or --static-libgcc compilation flags

Comment: Thanks for the hints. Unfortunately the flags didn't change anything to the better (ld complained about not finding -lc - I didn't investigate that issue any further). We now resorted to the workaround of including the two missing libraries in our install package so the target machines can run the provided binaries. A test in the staging environment proved that the app compiled on Solaris 10 (with the two new libs included) yields the same results as the previous version compiled in Solaris 8 - so from our point of view it's not the prettiest solution but one that works. Thanks everyone!